# capture commands executed remotely using SSH in Auditd

Tags: audit, logging

I have configured Auditd in a RHEL6 server and enabled TTY logging using

```
pam_tty_audit.so enable=*
```

in /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/password-auth

I don't have any other rules configured in audit.rules file as I am interested in only logging commands executed by users and not tracking all process activities

I am able to see the commands executed by users locally in this server.
But if users are executing commands remotely from other servers using SSH, like

`ssh userid@<rhel server> date`

these commands are not logged in audit logs.. 
Is there any way to log these ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit /etc/pam.d/sshd to audit ssh

look here https://blog.shichao.io/2015/04/22/auditing_user_tty_and_root_commands_with_auditd_on_ubuntu.html

Comment: You should post the instructions here, not just a link.

Comment: My first line is the instruction..the link is a reference